# How to use Mockito to mock a request in Jersey client?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, jersey-client

I have a class to post POJO to an external API. I want to test this method.

```
public int sendRequest(Event event) {

   Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
   WebTarget baseTarget = client.target(some url);
   Invocation.Builder builder = baseTarget.request();
   Response response = builder.post(Entity.entity(event, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
   int statusCode = response.getStatus();
   String type = response.getHeaderString("Content-Type");


  if (Status.Family.SUCCESSFUL == Status.Family.familyOf(statusCode)) {
        m_log.debug("The event was successfully processed by t API %s", event);
  }

  else if (Status.Family.CLIENT_ERROR == Status.Family.familyOf(statusCode)) {
      m_log.error("Status code : <%s> The request was not successfully processed by API. %s", statusCode, event);
  }

  return statusCode;
 }
```

I wrote a unit test like this

```
@Test
  public void sendRequest_postAuditEvent_returnOK() {
  int statusCode = EventProcessor.sendRequest(event);
  assertEquals(Status.OK.getStatusCode(), statusCode);
 }
```

But this will send a real request to the API. I am new to Mockito. Can anyone help me how to mock this request?

Edit:

```
@Mock Client m_client;
@Mock WebTarget m_webTarget;
@Mock Invocation.Builder m_builder;
@Mock Response m_response;

@Test
public void sendRequest_postAuditEvent_returnOK() {
  when(m_client.target(anyString())).thenReturn(m_webTarget);
  when(m_webTarget.request()).thenReturn(m_builder);
  when(m_builder.post(Entity.entity(m_AuditEvent, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))).thenReturn(m_response);
  when(m_response.getStatus()).thenReturn(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode());
  assertEquals(Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode(), m_AuditEventProcessor.sendRequest(m_AuditEvent));
}
```

I try to mock the methods but it doesn't work. Still call the real method.

Comment: You could use [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/) to test the communication between clients and servers.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the class should take a `Client` in its constructor so you could replace the real client instance with a mock when testing it.

```
class EventProcessor {
    private Client client;

    public EventProcessor(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public int sendRequest(Event event) {
        WebTarget baseTarget = client.target(some url);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use powerMockito like this post [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

If you can mock this returned object ClientBuilder.newClient() you can mock all the other objects in the call chain.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClientBuilder.class);
BDDMockito.given(ClientBuilder.newClient(...)).willReturn([a Mockito.mock()...]);
```